# Reverse geocoding with SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm facing a low performance issue in a new development probably someone had facing before. There are many way to perform the reverse geocoding process. I have a stored procedure to get reverse geocoder.

The issue is the table which have the "road segments(as geography)" is a very large table with approximate 624801 rows.

For single reverse geocoder it is taking 2 sec on desktop computer, however it is too much time if you keep in mind we have 1000 vehicles on field requesting reverse geocoding services each minute, it means i have to improve lot the service performance. Can you help to reduce the query time?

Thanks in advance

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES *, b.GEOGraphy.STDistance(@input) AS dist 
FROM Numbers n 
JOIN UK b WITH(INDEX(spatial_geography_index)) -- index hint 
    ON b.Geography.STDistance(@input) < @start*POWER(CAST(2 AS FLOAT),n.n) 
    AND b.Geography.STDistance(@input) >= CASE 
        WHEN n = 1 THEN 
            0 
        ELSE 
            @start*POWER(CAST(2 AS FLOAT),n.n-1) 
        END 
WHERE n <= 10 
ORDER BY n   )

SELECT TOP 1 @name=Name, 
FROM NearestNeighbor 
ORDER BY n,dist
```

Comment: Can you please post the sp you're running as well as information on any table indices?

Comment: my sp contains nearest neighbour as explained by issac in microsoft http://blogs.msdn.com/b/isaac/archive/2008/10/23/nearest-neighbors.aspx

Comment: SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES *, b.GEOGraphy.STDistance(@input) AS dist FROM Numbers n JOIN UK b WITH(INDEX(spatial_geography_index)) -- index hint
    ON b.Geography.STDistance(@input) < @start*POWER(CAST(2 AS FLOAT),n.n)
    AND b.Geography.STDistance(@input) >= 
   CASE WHEN n = 1 THEN 0 ELSE @start*POWER(CAST(2 AS FLOAT),n.n-1) END
   WHERE n <= 10
   ORDER BY n  
  )SELECT TOP 1     @name=Name,    
   FROM NearestNeighbor
   ORDER BY n,dist

Comment: do you got any solution yet ?

Answer (score 1):

As with any geodata query, you can speed things up if you know a little about your reality vs your data.

For example, do you have any info on where particular vehicles are supposed to be? Do they run regular routes? Does each truck have a number which correlates to a particular region on a given day? If so, you can narrow down searching on just those rows be providing a range in which you expect to find results (then expanding if needed)... though really this is just an extension of the method Isaac Kunin already suggests.

Isaac Kunin offers good insight in how to quickly find geodata **knowing that you have nearby neighbors** but his method may underperform if your sample space needs to grow a great deal before encountering a neighbor. Even then, it requires you to know a bit about the reality if your data... like how big is appropriate for an iterative search?

The bottom line is this:

For any query, if you do not wish to scan all your data you must first decide on an appropriate way to narrow your search. This requires some intimacy with your data and some intelligent design based on reality of your use-cases.

Comment: Thanks Matthew. I will go through my use cases and will see

Answer (score 0):

Two ideas come to mind initially:

1. I think you could create a search index (using something like Sphinx) that would allow you to do extremely fast lookups, but you'd have to take care in creating the index given your needs.  You may want to set the lat/lng as an attribute such that there is always a single match, then do all the reverse geocode lookups using the lat/lng as filters.  http://sphinxsearch.com/
2. Would you be willing to rely on an external API or do you have too much traffic for that? Google exposes a reverse geocoding API here: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=true_or_false

Comment: I don't want to use external API. I am developing a standalone application to get this done using c#.